# Как в меню добавить сепаратор, если оно заполняется элементами от ICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Придумал такую схему.

Создал класс

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand, ICollection<MyCommand>
```

То есть каждая команда включает еще вложенные команды (вложенные меню)

В классе окна добавляю свойство

```
public MyCommand Menu { get; set; }
```

В дизайнере делаю так

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu}"/>
```

И так же в ресурсы окна добавляю вот что

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyCommand}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Все. В коде формирую дерево из `MyCommand`, и меню в окне создается автоматически по дереву. Класс `MyCommand` реализует слияние, так что я спокойно могу добавлять к основному меню дополнительные пункты (например меню, которое создано в контенте `TabItem`).

Все гениально и просто :), вот только я не знаю, как отделить пункты меню сепараторами. Я ведь не оперирую контейнерами (MenuItem), поэтому не могу просто взять и добавить `new Separator()`. Посоветуйте что нибудь для этого.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разделитель — это часть представления, а не вью-модели. Идея делать маппинг один-к-одному между абстрактными командами и элементами управления во всём приложении — порочна. Подобный подход может использоваться в отдельных случаях, например, при генерации списка недавно открытых файлов в меню или предоставлении плагину абстрактного интерфейса для управления представлением (и то я бы задумался об альтернативах).

Запихнуть разделитель в список можно. Всего-то нужно сделать иерархию классов ("пункт меню", "пункт меню-разделитель", "пункт меню-команда"), присыпать шаблончиками и биндингами... Но хорошо задумайтесь: а правильно ли это? Если вы пойдёте по пути маппинга один-к-одному между элементами управления и вью-моделями, то вы превратите MVVM в фарс: у вас в слое вью-моделей появится упрощённая проекция представления, и представление станет полностью управляться из слоя вью-моделей. Сама вью-модель превратится в помесь контроллера и презентера. Это уже не MVVM.

Короче, не надо так делать.

Comment: Посоветуйте иной способ. Я делаю это впервые и мне ничего другого в голову не пришло. Задача. Есть приложение. Приложение умеет выполнять какие-то команды. Есть у него несколько однотипных окон. Окна умеют выполнять команды. У каждого окна есть TabControl и вкладки. Контент каждой вкладки умеет выполнять команды. Вопрос, как запихнуть все это в меню? То есть отображаемое главное меню должно включать: команды приложения, команды окна и команды открытой вкладки.

Comment: Я не понял что значит *"маппинг один-к-одному"*. Попробуйте более подробно расписать, в чем мои ошибки, пожалуйста, указывая на код, который я приложил к вопросу.

Comment: @iRumba У вас GUI описывается не во вью, а во вью-модели, проблема вашего кода в этом. Меню надо полностью строить во вью, из вью ссылаться на операции из вью-модели. Если несколько меню надо слить, то это задача уровня вью, а не вью-модели. Соответственно, выносите слияние в attached behaviors, наследуйте меню, да хоть в code-behind пишите — любой этот вариант будет архитектурно правильнее.

Comment: Так меню имеет древовидную структуру. Так же как и TreeView. Дерево же я могу построить динамически, а почему динамическое построение меню считается неправильным? Объясните разницу, пожалуйста.

Comment: И еще вопрос. Допустим, я добавляю в проект новое окно. Создаются при этом 2 файла: Window.xaml и Window.xaml.cs. Xaml тут - это View, а cs - ViewModel?

Comment: Еще вопрос. Допустим у меня есть `TabItemControl1 : UserControl`, который является содержимым нужного таба на форме. Как мне задать у него меню и связать его с ViewModel данного контрола? Создать меню в ресурсах? А как и с чем биндить? Добавить в ViewModel свойство `public Menu Menu { get; set; }`? Ну, то есть как мне потом в окне извлекать это меню из контента таба?

Comment: @iRumba Когда у вас иерархическая модель с какими-то сущностями, в представлении вы можете сделать хоть TreeView, хоть вложенные списки, хоть попапы, хоть цепочку списков... когда у вас иерархия команд с пунктами меню, иконками и разделителями, вы можете сделать только меню, то есть намертво привязываетесь к элементам управления. / .xaml.cs — это code-behind. По-нормальному он должен быть стерильным (его вообще удалить можно), но можно поместить там другие классы, в том числе вью модель; можно накодить костылей, которые плохо списываются в MVVM, если городить поведения и контролы лень.

Comment: @iRumba Если меню — это иерархия MenuItem, которую как-то должен потребить контейнер контрола, то можно прицепить меню к контролу с помощью attached property.

Comment: Думал уже над attached property, какое то шестое чувство подсказывает мне, что в них мое спасение, но я не могу придумать реализацию (

Comment: @Discord: Отличный ответ. Положу-ка его в закладки.

Comment: @VladD Да наболело. У меня до сих пор перед глазами стоит пример использования мелкомягкого риббона (пример производства самих мелкомягких, замечу), где все свойства всех существующих контролов (которых вообще-то дофига) были перетащены во "вью-модель": табы, группы, разделители, надписи, иконки, размеры, порядок схлопывания и далее по списку.

Comment: @Discord: Это ещё ничего, я видел код, в котором в VM протащили позицию текстового курсора в `TextBox`'ах (facepalm.jpg).

Comment: Спорно все это. Конвертеры тоже часть вьюхи, но некоторые считают, что вьюмодель это "конвертер на стероидах" и их ничего не смущает. Хотя я против такого подхода и люблю делать конвертеры. Поэтому и задачу "разделять список команд" должен выполнять конвертер.

Answer (score 1):

**Отвечу не совсем на данный вопрос, но тоже про меню. Просто, в комментарии на [один вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462472/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83-mvvm) сказал, что покажу**

> вариант, как можно собрать меню...

**Сепараторы тут тоже используются.**

Чтобы собрать меню, можно реализовать сервис `AppCommandService`, который позволяет регистрировать в себе реализации `ICommand` и содержит свойство `Menu`, к которому можно привязаться из `xaml`.

Сразу скажу, что это не идеальная реализация такого сервиса, в том числе и потому что нельзя динамически добавлять и убирать пункты меню. Тут встроен IoC контейнер - Windsor, который в принципе можно заменить на другой контейнер или заменить коллекцией.

---

Смысл такой:

1) команде даешь атрибут, который содержит строку с названиями пунктов разделенными `\`:

```
[Menu(@"Файл\Сохранить Как\", "Сохранить Как PDF", Order = 2, Break = MenuBreak.Before)]
public class SaveAsPdfCommand: ICommand
{
    ...
}

//order - порядковый номер при отображении меню
//Break - указывать, если надо поставить СЕПАРАТОР
```

2) Регистрируешь эту команду в сервисе

```
CommandService.RegisterCommand<SaveAsPdfCommand>();
//CommandService = new AppCommandService() - публичное свойство вью модели
```

3) Привязываешься к `Xaml`:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding CommandService.Menu}"/>
```

---

**Реализация:**

Атрибут:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class MenuAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Path { get; protected set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public MenuAttribute(string path, string name)
        :this(path)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    protected MenuAttribute (string path)
    {
        Path = path;
        Break = MenuBreak.None;
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
    public MenuBreak Break { get; set; }

    public static MenuAttribute Extract(Type t)
    {
        var attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MenuAttribute), false).OfType<MenuAttribute>();
        if (attributes == null || attributes.Count() == 0) return null;

        MenuAttribute result = 
            attributes.FirstOrDefault(); //здесь можно вставить условие по выбору атрибута, если их много

        return result;
    }
}

public enum MenuBreak : byte
{
    None,
    Before,
    After,
    Both
}
```

---

Сервис:

```
public class AppCommandService 
{
    private IWindsorContainer _InternalContainer = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new StaticContentResource(@"<configuration></configuration>")));


    public void RegisterCommand<T>() where T: ICommand
    {
        _InternalContainer.Register(Component.For<ICommand, T>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
    }

    public T ResolveCommand<T>() where T : ICommand
    {
        return _InternalContainer.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public void Execute<T>(object parameter = null) where T : ICommand
    {
        var command = _InternalContainer.Resolve<T>();
        if (command != null && command.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            command.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteOnAppDispatcher<T>(object parameter = null) where T : ICommand
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>(Execute<T>), parameter);
    }

    #region MENU
    //MENU...

    private List<string> _DefaultMenuPaths = new List<string>();

    public void RegisterMenuPath(string path)
    {
        _DefaultMenuPaths.Add(path);
    }

    //сборка дерева меню из аттрибутов
    private IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetMenuItems()
    {
        var handlers = _InternalContainer.Kernel.GetHandlers(typeof(ICommand));



        var items = 
            (
                from x in handlers
                let attr = MenuAttribute.Extract(x.ComponentModel.Implementation)
                where attr != null
                orderby attr.Order
                let command = _InternalContainer.Resolve(x.ComponentModel.Implementation) as ICommand
                select new { attr, command}
            ).ToArray();

        var generatedItems = new Dictionary<string, MenuItem>();
        var menuRoots = new List<MenuItem>();

        foreach (var item in _DefaultMenuPaths)
        {
            var path = item.Split('\\');
            String currentPath = String.Empty;
            MenuItem parent = null;
            MenuItem lastItem = null;
            foreach (var menuPath in path)
            {
                currentPath += menuPath + "\\";
                parent = lastItem;
                if (!generatedItems.TryGetValue(currentPath, out lastItem))
                {
                    lastItem = new MenuItem() { Header = menuPath };
                    generatedItems.Add(currentPath, lastItem);
                    if (parent != null)
                    {
                        parent.Items.Add(lastItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menuRoots.Add(lastItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var path = PreparePath(item.attr.Path).Split('\\');
            MenuItem lastItem = null;
            MenuItem parent = null;
            String currentPath = String.Empty;

            foreach (var menuPath in path)
            {
                parent = lastItem;
                currentPath += menuPath + "\\";
                if (!generatedItems.TryGetValue(currentPath, out lastItem))
                {
                    lastItem = new MenuItem() { Header = menuPath };
                    generatedItems.Add(currentPath, lastItem);
                    if (parent != null)
                    {
                        parent.Items.Add(lastItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menuRoots.Add(lastItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            var menu = new MenuItem
            {
                Header = item.attr.Name,
                Command = item.command
            };

            if (lastItem != null)
            {
                if (item.attr.Break == MenuBreak.Before || item.attr.Break == MenuBreak.Both)
                {
                    lastItem.Items.Add(new Separator());
                }

                lastItem.Items.Add(menu);

                if (item.attr.Break == MenuBreak.After || item.attr.Break == MenuBreak.Both)
                {
                    lastItem.Items.Add(new Separator());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                menuRoots.Add(menu);
            }
        }

        return menuRoots;
    }

    protected ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _MenuItems;
        }
    }

    public void GenerateMenuItems()
    {
        MenuItems.Clear();
        foreach (var item in GetMenuItems())
        {
            MenuItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    //добвление child - контейнера, чтобы резолвить команды с инъекциями
    public AppCommandService(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        container.AddChildContainer(_InternalContainer);
    }

    //пустой конструктор, когда не надо вставлять зависимости
    public AppCommandService()
    {

    }

    private static string PreparePath(string path)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) return String.Empty;

        if (path[path.Length - 1] == '\\')
        {
            return path.Substring(0, path.Length - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return path;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Хм. `[Menu(@"Файл\Сохранить Как\", "Сохранить Как PDF", Order = 2, Break = MenuBreak.Before)]` — это же снова кодирование представления на уровне модели.

Comment: Сомнительное решение. Даже если забить на всякие MVVM и SRP, всё равно запихивание разделителей и порядка пунктов в атрибуты обернётся ночным кошмаром при правке. Да и создание отдельных классов под каждую команду не каждый день увидишь. При этом DI намекает на большой проект, а в большом проекте подобная архитектура смерти подобна.

Comment: Я вас понимаю. Хотя для нашего проекта такое решение подошло. Есть папочка с командами (названия пунктов берутся из констант). Одна команда выполняет одно самостоятельное действие - открывает окно или вкладку с отчетом (у нас Prism). Хотя возможно, в других случаях такое решение не подойдет. Пусть тогда будет висеть, как возможный вариант.

Comment: Если что, то можно атрибут заменить на другой класс (класс х), который бы создавался во вью-модели. А остальное примерно так же. Вью-модель бы запихивала эти классы-комманды в сервис, который бы был ее свойством и формировал дерево меню. Класс х бы реализовывал ICommand и имел дополнительные свойства, как порядок, наличие разделителя и, главное, path - по той же логике, что и в данном примере.

Comment: Спасибо, но меня не поймут, если я заставлю разработчиков табов так париться с меню. Моя задача облегчить им жизнь, а не усложнить :(